# SSMS - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 do not discover SQL Express network servers

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

I've 4 SQL Express servers on my network, and I'm able to connect to all of them with SSMS from the different computers across the network.
But I'm not able to see them in the SSMS "Browse for Servers" window if i'm doing a search (Browse for network servers).

I've tried to disable all firewalls, made firewall rules for TCP port 135, 1433, 1434 and 4022 and UDP port 1434 allowed for both in and out.
And servers has been set up for listening on port 1433. And the "SQL Server Browser" is running.

It is working with connection, but not able to browse them.
Does anyone know why, and if there is a fix for this?

Comment: Is your SQL Server Browser service running ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The SQL Server browser service is running, and tested it with the Powershell Get-NetUDPEndpoint command and i'm getting the LocalAddress 0.0.0.0 on LocalPort 1434

Comment: You only need udp/1434 for the SQL Server Resolution Protocol that the SQL Browser service implements. And you need to restart the SQL Browser service(s) after any configuration changes to the Server Protocol configurations of the instance(s).

Comment: You need the browser running on each of the hosts the instances are running on, not your host. The Browser doesn't expose hosts running on *other* hosts

Comment: Are the servers on the same subnet? UDP broadcast messages are not routed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning,  Larnu and Dan Guzman
 
The SQL Server browser port is not something to set up? I'm right?
All servers are on the same subnet, the SQL Browser is running on all servers, and the servers has been restarted several times... but the are connected through an ubiquiti edgeswitch ... Can that be the problem? regarding the UDP broadcast.

Comment: The first basic network test is to try this on the client machine: `Test-NetConnection <yourservername> -Port 1434` and see if it passes.. although I'm not sure if UDP works that way

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `Test-NetConnection` tests ping (ICMP) and TCP port connectivity.

Comment: Yeah OK doesn't work for UDP....

Comment: EdgeSwitches are intelligent switches that support VLANs. Are the SQL Servers not only on the same LAN but also the same VLAN? If VLANs are used there will be extra software installation and configuration required to support UDP broadcast across VLANs - but even then I'm not sure that SSRP is compatible with UDP broadcast in such a manner.

Comment: They are on the same VLan as well and another thing I do not understand is. Why it does not show the local instance as a network server, I remember it use to be that way in the past when using SSMS. And I've tried to use SQLCMD -L as well but i still don't get anything. And it is the same for both windows 10 and 11. If that help to clear things up a bit

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem, it was caused by VMware workstation on the computers. I found out about this, by using the `CMD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe" -c` like mentioned  in this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver16).

By stopping the "SQL Server Browser" Service, and start it from the CMD you get to see what happens in the service, And it was not as I expected. It seems like that the virtual network adapters from VMware was causing the problem, because it looking like the SQL server browser was using the wrong adapters.

It might be because I've installed the VMware workstation before the SQL server. But anyway by removing the adapters and using only a bridged connection from the VMware for now,  everything is working as expected.